# Collections.sort not working

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

I want to sort a list of Objects from the smallest to the biggest with their *Distance* value but it seems like i made some mistakes

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> readInput(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    int length = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        ArrayList<Pair> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] s = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Double distance = Double.parseDouble(s[i]);
            if (distance != 0) {
                temp.add(new Pair(i, distance));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(temp);
        list.add(temp);
    }
    in.close();
    return list;
}
```

class **Pair**:

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
private int index;
private double distance;
public int compareTo(Pair other){
    if (this.getDistance() == other.getDistance())
        return 0;
    else if (this.getDistance() > other.getDistance())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
public Pair(int index, double distance) {
    super();
    this.index = index;
    this.distance = distance;
}
public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}
public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}
public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
```

}

The **file** is just an adjacency matrix where value of **row-i,col-j** is the distance to go from vertex **i** to vertex **j**, something like:

```
4 // first line in the file is the number of vertices
0 1 5 6
4 2 3 1
1 8 9 2
0 0 5 3
```

Here is the testing result

> - 3.0133 - 2.0321 - 1.0373 - 1.0442 - 1.0488 - 1.0560 - 4.0950 - 1.0246 - 2.0501 - 1.0723 - 1.0285 - 2.0930 - 1.0953 - 1.0528 - 1.0748 - 1.0773 - 2.0731 - 2.0865 - 1.0327 - 1.0611 - 1.0621 - 1.0347 - 2.0688 - 3.014 - 3.055 - 1.0158 - 1.0808 - 1.0111 - 1.0198 - 1.0233

**UPDATED**:

It's working now, the problem is my printing method

Comment: can you please post data for file? also... what is `lenght` in the for loop? gives compilation error.....

Comment: well, **length** is just the length of an array i read from a file. Everything works well, except that it seems like that **sort** is not working

Comment: @DươngAnhKhoa It would really help if you could provide some example file

Comment: add **@Override** above the **compareTo** method  in class **Pair** :D

Comment: @nafas Override is just an annotation, it does nothing on the code.

Comment: strange, I just tried your code and it works for me... also are the input u provided an example? if not how are they related to output? then how are you printing the output?

Comment: silly mate, :P when you printing out ur output use **System.out.println** instead of **System.out.print**
u'll see the magic :D

Comment: your list is sorted , but it won't show because of the way you've printed it out

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
in.close();
return temp.OrderByDescending(x=> x.getDistance())
```

This will order the list in a descending fashion based on the value of getDistance().

Comment: The question is about Java, not C#.